# Lucidworks CMIS connector/data source?

Tags: alfresco, cmis, documentum, lucidworks

I want to integrate Lucidworks 2.5 enterprise search with CMIS compliant repositories as alfresco or documentum but i can not see any data source/connector for same. But on Lucidworks site @ http://www.lucidworks.com/about-us/press-releases/application-developers-worldwide-endorse-lucidworks-20-open-source-search-platform-creating i can see CMIS has been mentioned as OOTB connector.

> Thanks to the new LucidWorks Open Connector Framework, SHI will deliver connectors for the integration of LucidWorks 2.0 with Microsoft Exchange and IBM Lotus Notes, and CMIS-capable repositories such as Alfresco ECM and Documentum. These connectors help businesses extract valuable business insights from data stored in such systems. The Exchange connector will be available by the end of 2011 and Lotus Notes/CMIS connectors will be available in early 2012.

Can anybody help me on hwo can i achieve it? Is it OOTB available somewhere else or is it not available & needs to be created as custom component?

Regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is Markus Klose from SHI in Germany.
It is correct that we developed an CMIS Connector for LucidWorks Search. 
Some detailed information you can find on our website. 
http://www.shi-gmbh.com/images/files/cmis_connector_features_overview.pdf
Unfortunately it is in german, but please feel free to contact me if you have any questions

Phone: +49 821 748263326
Mail:  markus.klose@shi-gmbh.com

Answer (score 1):

It looks like [SHI](http://www.shi-gmbh.com/) is a separate company that developed the CMIS connector for LucidWorks.  It looks like you need to purchase it separately.

I found more information here (in German): http://www.shi-gmbh.com/loesungen/apache-solr-lucene/content-management-connector about the repositories it supports.

I also found an example query using the CMIS connector here: http://www.shi-gmbh.com/blog/example-queries-for-lucidworks-enterprise-cmis-connector-made-by-shi/